# How can I avoid bundling Vuetify and use from CDN?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm trying to decrease the bundle size of my Vue project, which scaffolded by the vue-cli, by using CDN of firebase, Vue, and Vuetify.

So, I've added links of these CDN in `public/index.html` as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>magiclabel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but t4v4 doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Add `config.externals` to `vue.config.js` as follow:

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.externals({
      firebase: 'firebase',
      'firebase/auth': 'firebase',
      firebaseui: 'firebaseui',
      vue: 'Vue',
      vuetify: 'Vuetify',
      'vuetify/lib': 'Vuetify',
    })
  }
}
```

Then, the `report.html` created by issueing `yarn build --report` indicated that the `Vuetify` is still **in the bundle** even other firebase and Vue is going away as follow:

[image]

Is there any wrong or insufficient steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vuetify from `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` (`vue add vuetify`), treeshaking and auto component import [is enabled by default](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/), by using `vuetify-loader`.

If you look into [the source code of `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/blob/26d9c20f59d546e583b8942108fc8972c71e7c1e/packages/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/index.js#L8-L11), it only uses `vuetify-loader` if it is present in your `package.json`. So removing `vuetify-loader` from `package.json` should disable this behavior.